# SSRS preview stopped working

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm using VS2017 and have added the parts necessary to use SSRS. I've created three reports and have successfully previewed them in VS. I deployed them to a report server and checked that they worked, and they didn't. The server reported an error. To solve that, I had to go into the *Data Source Properties -> Credentials* dialog and change the *Credentials* to "Use this user name and password."

That solved the error that the server reported. I deployed them once again, and they worked. However, now when I try to do a preview on any of the reports in VS, I get an error message that says:

an error occurred during local report processing

an error has occurred during report processing

I've already looked on here and Googled this, and most responses were for people using rdlc reports in applications, which I am not doing. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set the datasource back to a configuration that worked on your machine after making the changes so they would work server side?

Comment: Just tried that, @Ross Bush, and it worked. So I have to switch back and forth between DataSet configurations depending on what I'm doing? That's doable, but ridiculous.

Comment: Depending on your setup, you could get away with using localhost or another way so that when deployed, the connection string would work in both environments.

Comment: OK, thanks @Ross Bush!